# re.search valida também emails inválidos

Tags: python, regex, email, validation

Estou com alguns problemas nessa validação para e-mail. Qualquer texto que coloco ele valida e aceita. O que ocasiona isso?

```
import re

def email_validation(email):
        regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)$"
        try:
            if re.search(regex,email):
                return email        
        except:
            raise Exception("Email inválido")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Veja na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) que `search` retorna `None` se nada é encontrado, mas em nenhum momento ele lança exceção, então não vai cair no `except`. Então basta ver se o retorno é `None`, algo assim:

```
def email_validation(email):
    regex = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)$"
    if re.search(regex, email) is None:
        raise Exception('Email inválido')
    return email
```

Repare também que usei uma [*raw literal string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708) (com o "r" antes das aspas) para que a `\` seja corretamente interpretada dentro da expressão.

---

Mas na verdade não sei para que retornar o próprio email se ele for válido (e questiono se lançar exceção seria a melhor forma de validar), então outra sugestão é fazer a função retornar somente se o email é válido ou não (apenas `True` ou `False`):

```
# retorna True se o email é válido, False se for inválido
def email_validation(email):
    regex = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)$"
    return re.search(regex, email) is not None
```

E aí quem chama a função decide o que fazer com o resultado:

```
if email_validation('teste@teste.com'):
    print('email válido')
else:
    print('email inválido')
```

Aí você pode escolher se mostra uma mensagem, lança exceção, etc. A função só tem a responsabilidade de dizer se o email é válido ou não, o que acontece depois fica a cargo de quem chamá-la. Não vejo necessidade de lançar uma exceção se dá para resolver com um retorno *booleano*.

---

Outro detalhe é que a documentação diz que se uma expressão é usada várias vezes (como parece que vai ser o caso), [pode ser interessante compilá-la antes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

Então uma alternativa é usar `re.compile` para deixar a regex já compilada:

```
def email_validation(email, regex=re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)$")):
    return regex.search(email) is not None
```

Assim a regex é compilada apenas uma vez, e você pode chamar a função várias vezes sem ter que recriá-la. E colocando-a como parâmetro, é possível mudar a regex se quiser:

```
# valida usando a regex default
email_validation(email)

# valida usando outra regex
email_validation(email, re.compile('outra regex...'))
```

---

Por fim, não cheguei a analisar a regex. Mas sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas [aqui](/a/340617/112052), [aqui](/a/327150/112052), [aqui](/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).